# Bending a pole with wind

Tags: mesh

Hi I am doing a simple 2D animation using mesh. It is a bicycle with a flag. I want the fhe flag and its pole to move acording to the wind. With the flag I hava no problem, however I could not find a way of making the pole bend with the wind. Is it something possible to be done? Would the only possible solution be to use bones?

Comment: I haven't tried this before, but I wonder if it might be possible to use a b-bone and have the wind values as drivers? Like I said, I haven't tried it before, but it's some food for thought.

Comment: it is not clear if you need a manually animated movement, or (as the word "wind" could make think of) a dynamic behaviour.  also, I believe that in your example more  different factors could count in: if there's "wind" the flag would move even when the bicycle is still, stopped. when bicycles moves, two more factors could contribute: air resistance and inertia. both could bend your pole...

Comment: I've made a whip antenna bending in the wind with the 'vehicle's motion which looks good but just noticed that you were wanting a rod or pole for your flag.   If a whip style will do leave a comment and I can post it up  It's not difficult to create and have it oscillating with the wind as little or as much as you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Final result:

[image]

It's animated wind with changing strength.

### Steps:

1. Create **Cylinder** with only **6 vertices** and some small radius (for me it's 5cm).
2. Go to **Edit Mode** and add **3 Loop Cuts**.
3. Select bottom **Edge Loops** and add them to **Vertex Group**.

[image: 2]

4. Exit **Edit Mode** and add **Soft Body** physics to our cylinder.
5. First set the **Goal Strength** to **1** and as **Vertex Group** select the one we created before.
6. Add some wind to test it out.
7. Go to **Soft Body Edges** tab and **Soft Body Self Collision** and make changes accordingly to picture below.

[image: 3]

8. That's it.

### Final thoughts:

If you want it to look smooth, add **Edge Creases 1** to top and bottom edge loop, select **Shading Smooth**, turn on **Auto Smooth** and add **Subdivision Surface** modifier.

***Note.*** Settings may differ accordingly to edge loops count, pole length and such.
You will want to tweak then such values as **Pull**, **Push** and **Bending**.

***Note 2.*** To control jiggling and bending strength change **Soft Body Mass**.

### Blend file:

[image]