# How to bend parts of mesh with a force field?

Tags: physics, force-fields

I'd like to make feathers on a tail of a model bend to the force fields. I've tried some tutorials but after spending whole day trying different methods, none of them worked propely. For example in this tutorial:
-> [Bending a pole with wind](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74409/bending-a-pole-with-wind) <-
I selected all the feathers and added them to the vertex groups, like this

[image]

then I followed rest of steps in the tutorial. Unfotunately when i started animation with wind, whole program started to lag extremely and crashed.
Then I tried to use Cloth physics, but it didn't work as rest of model completly colapsed as soon as I played the animation.
So far I can't figure out how to make that part of mesh bend propely with force fields, I'll be glad for any help!

Comment: One way would maybe be hair-dynamics. Put a hair particle system on tail object, use a weight map to grow them where you want them to grow (might be a bit of a mare trying to get the pointing where you want them to though!), and enable hair dynamics. Then add a 'particle instance modifier to your feather object and chose the tail object & particle system in the modifier. Then mess with the hair stiffness etc.

Comment: Here's some wheat I used this method on- https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8a6p08plff3wkw/WheatVariations.mkv?dl=0 So a hair particle system on the plain, and a few 'wheat' objects instanced onto the hair, then blown about with wind & turbulance. Like I said it needs some messing with values but it can work...

Comment: alright! I'll try to do it (might have to watch some tutorials tho) and let know how it worked out. Thanks.

Comment: Okay I made it! I found this tutorial to be helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOm2K9jOZLI&t

instead of drops I copied feathers from main object and splitted them from it, made vertex group in place where I wanted them to be and applied them to it. Now I just need to play around with settings to make them behave correctly because they act kind of strange to the forcefields and they dont follow rest of object in a correct way. Thank you for pointing out such a ways.

Comment: no sweat.......